# WPF databinding through nested custom user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I am attempting to do the following:

1. Have a main window that creates some objects with some information
2. This main window then has a custom user control as its content
3. This custom user control then has sub user controls that, in essence, represent different aspects of the objects created in the main window. In addition, it allows for that data to be interacted with by changing numbers and recalculating.

For some reason, likely because I am really new to WPF, databinding etc. I cannot figure out how to pass an element of a list to the bottom level user control to display its information. I have pasted what I have below. I am getting a object reference not set to an instance of an object from the button_label_tester as it tries to set the string of the textblock. I also see there is a warning in main_user_control.xaml where the binding to the list element is "No datacontext found for binding 'list_dose_objs[0]'.

I am sure I am missing something obvious but been stuck for a while. Would appreciate any help. I know this isn't really MVVM and all that, I am mainly trying to test and get my head around databindings and passing values around before devling into best practices.

## MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="GUI_tester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI_tester"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## MainWindow CS

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GUI_tester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {


            dose_object dose_obj1 = new dose_object(100, 1, 200);
            dose_object dose_obj2 = new dose_object(50, 2, 300);
            dose_object dose_obj3 = new dose_object(300, 3, 200);

            var main_UC = new GUI_tester.main_user_control();
            main_UC.list_dose_objs.Add(dose_obj1);
            main_UC.list_dose_objs.Add(dose_obj2);
            main_UC.list_dose_objs.Add(dose_obj3);
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = main_UC;


        }
    }
}

public class dose_object
{

    public double current_dose {get; set;}
    public double current_fraction { get; set; }
    public double limit_dose { get; set; }

    public dose_object(double current_dose, double current_fraction, double limit_dose)
    {
        this.current_dose = current_dose;
        this.current_fraction = current_fraction;
        this.limit_dose = limit_dose;
    }
}
```

## First level user control (main_user_control) XAML

```
    <UserControl x:Class="GUI_tester.main_user_control"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI_tester"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:GUI_tester"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="test"/>
        <TextBlock Text="test"/>
        <TextBlock Text="test"/>
        <uc:button_label_tester curr_dose_obj="{Binding Path=list_dose_objs[0]}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

## First level user control (main_user_control) CS

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GUI_tester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for main_user_control.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class main_user_control : UserControl
    {
        public List<dose_object> list_dose_objs = new List<dose_object>();
        public main_user_control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = list_dose_objs;
        }
    }
}
```

## The last user control that represents the object in some way (right now placeholder)

### Xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="GUI_tester.button_label_tester"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI_tester"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" d:Background="White">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Name="editable_text" Width="100" />
        <TextBlock Name="textblock_display"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

### CS

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GUI_tester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for button_label_tester.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class button_label_tester : UserControl
    {
        
        public button_label_tester()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += Button_label_tester_Loaded;
        }

        private void Button_label_tester_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            editable_text.Text = curr_dose_obj.current_dose.ToString();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty curr_dose_objProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("curr_dose_obj", typeof(dose_object), typeof(UserControl));
        public dose_object curr_dose_obj
        {
            get { return (dose_object)GetValue(curr_dose_objProperty); }
            set { SetValue(curr_dose_objProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to display a collection of UserControls that each visualize the data of a collection of data items, use an ItemsControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Besides that, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Remove the DataContext assignment from the main_user_control constructor and write `curr_dose_obj="{Binding Path=list_dose_objs[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Since data binding works with public properties only, declare it as `public List<dose_object> list_dose_objs { get; } = new List<dose_object>();`

Comment: Thanks for your response. For anyone curious, the last statement of making the list a property with a get was what was required to fix the issue.

Comment: And of course not setting the DataContext. `Path=list_dose_objs[0]` would not have worked with `this.DataContext = list_dose_objs;`

Comment: Sorry, yes that too! I am starting to see more how I was flawed in my code above. Still have quite a bit to learn! Appreciate your help very much. Currently working my way through WPF unleashed 4.5 and pretty amazing how this stuff was put together!

I guess a better way to design this would be the create a intermediate class that contains all the information/properties that I need and then bind that to the datacontext of the window which would then make it accessible to all child user controls?  I think that's what I have gathered about the MVVM paradigm but know that it is still incomplete

Comment: That book helped me very much 15 years ago. And it is still the best.